# HTML + Javascript: How to prevent videos from ever being played?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to override `video` tags completely so that they can never be played. Is there a way to do this globally so that ALL video tags that are loaded within the page after executing my javascript function will not be playable?

I want to run it on a site like Youtube, so that on the initial load of youtube.com, I'll load my javascript function and every time a user clicks into a video (which just makes an XHR request, not full page refresh), it won't play.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
var videoSelector = document.someMethodToFindSelector("video");
videoSelector.play = function() {}; // override play method so that it is a noop.
```

I want it to happen not just for the current `video` tags on the page, but all the ones that appear after.

Comment: remove the vidoe tags and replace with image

Comment: i want it to do it for all videos. similar to how jquery does `live` or `on` so that all elements with that selector will behave a certain way even if they are inserted dynamically

Comment: You need to run that code after you do anything that loads new content into the page.